# how do you remove repeated strings in java?

Tags: java

Input: 3 3 2 1

Desired output: 3 2 1

(the spaces should remain)

I tried to use this method but it does not work

```
public String filterRepeats(String s) 
{
        return new LinkedHashSet<String(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s"))).toString();
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `>` : `new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s"))).toString();`

Comment: You'd also get the raw output of the collection print statement, so you'd get brackets as included output.  You're shockingly close to this, think about a sort of *joiner* for *Strings* that you could leverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. If you are concerned about the brackets of the `toString` method. Just build a new string from the `LinkedHashSet`. For example:

```
public String filterRepeats(String s) {
        LinkedHashSet<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s")));

        String result = "";
        for (String elt : set) {
            result += elt + " ";

        }
        // trim last space
        result = res2.substring(0, result.length()-1);
        return result;

}
```

Comment: My pleasure. If you are satisfied with the answer you should mark it as the accepted answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Caution! The below code is expensive, If you just need it work then you can do it in the below way.

```
String a = "a b c d a b c";
Set<String> foo = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a.split(" ")));
a = foo.toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]","").replaceAll(","," ");
```

If you are using Java 8, streams will simplify your job, you need not use the `replaceAll` method at all. Check the below statement.

```
a = foo.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Cheers!

Comment: change Hashset to LinkedHashSet.

Comment: @dkb Yes, I didn't realize order was important there, LinkedHashSet preserves the order. I have updated according to your comment. Thanks anyway!